# Can you use project.json in an azure service fabric project?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to use project.json to make managing packages easier in a Service Fabric project.

However it is failing and I think it is due to not including ServiceFabricServiceModel.dll in the services. I can see the dll in the nuget packages in C:\Users\nick.nuget\packages\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors\2.0.135\lib\net45, but the nuspec file does not reference it.

There are quite a few errors when trying to deploy.

For example

```
Exception thrown during async task execution
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceFabricServiceModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'ServiceFabricServiceModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Common.FabricServiceConfigSection.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport.FabricTransportServiceRemotingProviderAttribute.CreateServiceRemotingListener(ServiceContext serviceContext, IService service)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulServiceReplicaAdapter.<OpenCommunicationListenersAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulServiceReplicaAdapter.<System.Fabric.IStatefulServiceReplica.ChangeRoleAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = ServiceFabricServiceModel, Version=5.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/SfDevCluster/Data/_App/_Node_1/SceneSkopePlatformType_App0/ServiceRegistrationServicePkg.Code.1.1.13 (2016-04-05 16.10.16Z)/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services, Version=5.0.0.0,         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_1\SceneSkopePlatformType_App0\ServiceRegistrationServicePkg.Code.1.1.13 (2016-04-05 16.10.16Z)\ServiceRegistrationService.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: ServiceFabricServiceModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the Service Fabric Reliable Actor/Service from a non-service fabric application?

Comment: No - I'm trying to write a service fabric actor but as a new dotnet project rather than a csproj. This may not be relevant any more with project.json apparently going away

Comment: Check out the answer by Azhar on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656598/bad-dll-file-exception-when-using-the-service-fabric-template/37201420#37201420

Comment: That comment is about x64. This question is about using project.json instead of a csproj

Answer (score 0):

This is a breaking change how dotnet cli handles not listed assemblies in nuget packages. For "old style" projects VS2015 copies this assembly to the project output, but the dotnet cli does not.

Until it's fixed, you can either wrap the assembly or copy it to the output in a postpublish step.
The assembly is downloaded to:
%userprofile%.nuget\packages\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services\2.0.135\lib\net45

Comment: I tried tracing where the problem is and it's likely with the nuget package not dotnet. The .nuspec file only lists one reference file, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.dll. ServiceFabricServiceModels.dll is missing from the .nuspec file. If you look at a similar package `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data` two dll files are listed and they are copied over to the bin folder by dotnet. I checked version 2.0.217. Is this a bug?

Comment: could you provide an example on how to postpublish the file until it is fixed?

Comment: found the answer in the [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/web-publishing-vs.html).  in ```project.json``` add section ```"scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "xcopy ..\\pathtofile %publish:OutputPath%" ]
  }```

Comment: Here's the exact command:
    "scripts": {"postpublish": [ "xcopy ..\\packages\\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.2.0.217\\lib\\net45\\ServiceFabricServiceModel.dll %publish:OutputPath%" ] }

Answer (score 0):

MSFT solved this in the latest nuget package version `2.1.150`